# Is possible to use negative exponents in FFT Algorithm?

Tags: sum, fft

I want to apply the FFT to discover all possible sum in two vector.

Let's say it's a = [-1,2,3] and b = [4,5].

I wanted to use FFT to find all possible sums, putting the numbers of the vector as exponents of two polynomials, with all coefficients equal 1, and multiply them. The exponents of the resultant polynomial would be all possible sums and its coefficients would be their frequency.

I know this works with positive numbers, but I wonder if FFT might work in this case as well.

Comment: None of the FFT algorithms that I have come across use negative exponents.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: It will work with positive and negative indeces, of course.   sin(x) =1/2i (e^(i x) + e^(- ix) . In fact that is how one can easily derive the trig. theorems.    e^(ix)^2 = e^(inx), then split into cosines and sines

Comment: But I'm not sure you need to do this numerically if you have the actual numbers. Why not just use sympy?